# Windows thinks foreign IP address is local hostname?

Tags: linux, windows, mysql, ip, hostname

I've spent the whole day trying to fix this and it's driving me absolutely insane. I noticed the issue while trying to set up a remote mySQL server and then went from there.  My manager can connect to the mySQL server at 192.168.242.26, using a mySQL GUI it shows him as being root@'192.168.242.26'. When I try the exact same GUI on the same server it shows me as root@'ThisisCompanyD-PC.local' (which apart from .local is my machines hostname).

I checked my HOSTS file and it doesn't refer to ThisisCompanyD-PC anywhere, it the usual 127.0.0.1 localhost loop and some specific ones for virtual hosts on a development server (the same one running mySQL).

My machine is running Vista, my manager has a XP machine and the server is running Ubuntu 10.04lts (Or Lucid Lynx if you prefer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that adding `skip-host-cache` to the mySQL config (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in Ubuntu) file worked. Thanks for your help, maybe I'll be able to get around to writing some PHP at last!

Answer (score 1):

Hi this should answer your question.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dns.html

Also check the comments on the article.

Comment: Thank you, this lead me to the answer. I'll try and bump my reputation up to 15 so I can vote up!

Comment: no points sad face :(